# Keyboard shortcut to launch Nemo

Tags: linux-mint, keyboard-shortcuts, nemo

In Windows you can type <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd> to launch the file explorer. I find this really useful, particularly because almost every action I take starts with search for a file or folder.

Is there an equivalent keyboard shortcut to launch Nemo in Linux Mint? (In an ideal world, there'd also be a way to run a file/folder search from the keyboard)

Comment: Using Mint Linux. Windows key + E launched the file explorer, just like Windows!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know the exact answer to your question. But this may help.

I am using Fedora and not Mint however I still believe this should work.

There are different shortcut keys assigned for a particular type of command execution.You can find them in your `System -> Preferences -> [System] ->Keyboard Shortcuts.`

You will also see various different kind of keys (symbols) used in there like
`XF86Mute` for Audio Mute, `XF86Calculator` for Calculator. These  i think are related to the special keys which comes in your PC/laptop.

If you are not able to determine the one for opening the HOME folder or the SEARCH button just change it in there like i changed SEARCH for `"Windows Key + S"` and for HOME DIR i made it "Windows Key + H".

Comment: Great! In Mint it's under `System Settings > Keyboard > Keyboard shortcuts > Launchers`.

Comment: Note that `Search` doesn't work in my Linux Mint 17. See [this SE question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/154569/linux-mint-search-launcher-doesnt-do-anything) for details.

Comment: I think the SEARCH key binding is related to the HOME key binding. I found this  working only after when i have issued the HOME keyboard shortcut. Check if that works for you. But I am not sure if we can have a SEARCH key binding irrespective of DIRECTORIES. Lets see what answers you get on your question.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @MikeCraffey: this now "just works". Pressing `Super`+`E` opens the `Files` window.

Answer (score 0):

In Mint Mate 17.3, this still needs to be configured from a fresh install. It's easily doable by going to `Menu -> Preferences -> Keyboard Shortcuts` and adding a new `Custom Shortcut` to the preferred file manager.

Doing this binds the shortcut to <kbd>Mod4</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd>. Unfortunately, if no other changes are made, this will not work when using the left Super key, only when using the one on the right side of the keyboard.

When you press the left Super key, regardless of any custom shortcuts, the menu will appear and the second keystroke will be ignored. This is because the Mate menu is bound to <kbd>Super_L</kbd>, not <kbd>Mod4</kbd>.

The only solution I've found is to change the key assigned to opening the Mate menu: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Super_L</kbd> for instance.

This setting can be changed by right clicking `Menu`, going to `Preferences`, then changing the shortcut on the `Main button` tab.

It's not a very elegant solution, but it does allow the file manager to be launched with <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> using the Super key on the left side of the keyboard.