# Linux Mint Search launcher doesn't do anything

Tags: linux-mint, keyboard-shortcuts, nemo

In Mint 17, using Cinnamon, if I go to `System Settings > Keyboard > Keyboard shortcuts > Launchers` there is an option to set a shortcut for something called `Search`.

However, whatever key binding I set this to, it doesn't seem to do anything. What is this supposed to do, and how do I make it do it?

Comment: What desktop environment are you using? Cinnamon? MATE? Gnome? Something else? I can confirm the same issue with my LMDE Cinnamon. Looks like a bug.

Comment: I think the SEARCH key binding is related to the HOME key binding. I found this working only after when i have issued the HOME keyboard shortcut. Check if that works for you. But I am not sure if we can have a SEARCH key binding irrespective of DIRECTORIES. I am using Fedora 20 Mate DE.

Comment: @bluefoggy issuing `Super`+`E` first brings up the home directory, but the search shortcut still does nothing.